# How to hide the value of a button element?

Tags: html, css

How can I hide the value of a button, while still showing the button?  I am using color: transparent; but that doesn't work.

I want to hid the value of the button, but not all of the button.  I need to keep the value attribute in the button; I just don't want it to be visible.

Comment: button vlaue i.e text ob button right ?

Comment: The value "transparent" isn't valid for the [color property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-color).

Comment: just i want to hide the value of the button not all the button.
i need this treatement and i don't see why the voting down here i just want to keep time for this i am posting the question here

Comment: @kawtousse - Is my answer not good enough, I've updated it.

Comment: +1 to complement unexplained mass-downvoting. (Even though I don't think it's a good question, it's still a valid one.)

Comment: lol.. yeah I'm upvoting this as well.  down with the downvoters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer that Nathan Reed proposed is I think the best one. But as you said you need the value, so I think this is what you need 
`<input type="button" value="my value" style="color: buttonface;">`

Comment: This doesn't work, the shades of the text are completely wrong in IE8, IE7, IE6 and FireFox 3.6 (at the very least)

Comment: I don't see any shades on my IE8 and Mozilla. What kind of shades are u talkin' about?

Answer (score 2):

Here, this will work in IE and FireFox:

CSS:

```
  input.noText {
    color: transparent;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 200px; /* set width */
    height: 25px; /* fixed height */
    *margin-left: 9999px; /* IE6 only */
    font-size: 0px;
    line-height: 16px; /* retains height */
  }
```

HTML:

```
  <input type="button" value="moo" class="noText" />
```

Comment: it hide all the button this is not what i want.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the button to display without any text on it, set the value as an empty string, then set the height and width of the button manually.

Comment: why do you need the value? if you just need to store it on the form, then use a hidden input field. I feel like you are going about this the wrong way...

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue.  Just use CSS to set the font-size to 0px.  Then it will be too tiny to see and just set background-image to whatever you want the button to look like and the height and width to that of the image you are using.  Then the value can be whatever you need it to be, but the button will look like whatever you set it to be, independently of the button's value.

Comment: This was perfect! thanks

Answer (score 2):

This [method](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/remove-button-text-in-ie7/) is perfect in my case, I used:

```
input.button { text-indent: -9000px; text-transform: capitalize; }
```

I tested it in FF, Opera, Chrome, Safari, IE9, IE8 and IE7