# Pass php value of a selected Submit image

Tags: php, html, forms

I have an image swiper, that changes between 3 images accoording to the below code. When I select image 1 or 2, I want that value to be sent to next page (submit form page). As for now only Image3 is always sent to the next page.

```
<form method="get" action="order.php"> 
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <div class="portfolio-details-slider swiper">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper align-items-center">

            <div class="swiper-slide">
              <input type="submit" value='<?php $var = "Image1";?>' style="background-image: url('img/portfolio/img4.jpg');">
            </div>

            <div class="swiper-slide">
              <input type="submit" value='<?php $var = "Image2";?>' style="background-image: url('img/portfolio/img7.jpg');">
            </div>

            <div class="swiper-slide">
              <input type="submit" value='<?php $var = "Scooter3";?>' style="background-image: url('img/portfolio/img8.jpg');">
            </div>
          <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div> 
    <input type='hidden' name='var' value='<?php echo "$var";?>'/>
    <input type='hidden' name='fail' value='<?php echo "$fail";?>'/>
</form>
```

How can I get the correct image value to be sent to the next page?

Comment: Without js thats not possible I would guess

Comment: Try to add hidden input to every submit input with image name value and then check which submit was pressed and then just send it to next page

Comment: this code is doing nothing  `value='<?php $var = "Image2";?>'` etc. Set the value directly with `echo`

Comment: Thanks for opening up my eyes. It was solved by adding  name="var"  &  value='<?php echo "Image2"; ?>'.  One issue was created though,  the echo value is printed on the image. Can this be hidden in some way?  I tried with hidden attribute but didn't work.

Comment: The value attribute issue was solved by setting font size to 0px. Same problem as in this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911746/how-to-hide-the-value-of-a-button-element